# I want to add single quotes in the below code ('')

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, automation

```
let name=Response.name;
```

//suppose in name i am getting name=Manav

now what i need to do is

```
con.query("Select * from accounts_master where name="(name)
```

i want Manav as 'Manav' in the above line i.e
Select * from accounts_master where name='Manav'

Please help for the same

Comment: What library do you use for DB connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use prepared statements instead of simple string concatenation or templates:

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM accounts_master WHERE name = ?', [name], (err, rows) => {
  console.log(rows);
})
```

Doing otherwise may leave you vulnerable to SQL injection attack, as [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) demonstrates.